# Ionic Cordova Android build error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I'm trying to build an Android version of a "blank" project with IONIC, now i'm stuck with this error. Has anyone experienced this before, and what would your answer be?

FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.179 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).

Comment: Check whether your ANDROID_HOME variable is set. Also can you elborate on the Steps and commands u tried to get this error.

Comment: ANDROID_HOME has been set to the SDK path, JAVA_HOME to 1.8 path.

Other paths: 
%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools,
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\sdkmanager,
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools,
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools,
%JAVA_HOME%\bin.

In console:
$ ionic cordova build android. This gives me the error. I've must overlooked something. @Lokkeshwaran

Comment: Found out it has to do with Android itself. I prepared the Android version with the command: ionic cordova prepare android, then I opened the build with Android Studio.Then I adjusted the build.gradle file, commented 
    //debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    //releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")) and added:       compile project(':CordovaLib')

Answer (score 1):

The way i solved this problem is as below:

1. `npm uninstall cordova ionic`
2. `npm install -g cordova@7.0.0 ionic@3.19.0`
3. `cordova platform rm android`
4. `cordova platform add android`